# Three-word phrase stress ("little straw house" vs. "small wooden house")

Tags: phrases, adjectives, stress

I'm interested to learn why the following three-word phrases have stress on different words.

1. "little straw house" (stress is on *little* and *house*)
2. "small wooden house" (stress is on *wooden*)

Here are the sentences:

> 1. The first little pig built a little straw house.
> 2. The second little pig built a small wooden house.

How come the stress for the second phrase is not on *small* and *house*?

Can you please help?

Comment: The stress is where you put it and depends on what you wish to emphasize.  The stress could very well be on *straw* in the first sentence.

Comment: My default reading puts a bit more stress on the first and third words of both phrases (as well as a descending tone throughout each phrase).

Comment: english stress assignment has been analyzed almost to death by linguists. would you like some references to consult?

Comment: I find the second of two adjectives is usually more stressed than the first, so to stress *little* in example 1 sounds rather odd; it's deliberately drawing attention to the size. Given the rather esoteric stress patterns of my Nigerian colleague, I guess which words/syllables are stressed depends entirely on region/dialect.

Comment: @AndrewLeach- Consider the following scenario:  You and your friend are running away from a zombie.  You say, "Quick hide in that straw house." Your friend says, "Which one there are 3 of them?"  You say, "The little straw house."  Now where did you put the stress?

Comment: Hahah Thanks everyone. This is crazy! Everything happens instantaneously! What are the references available? :) I'm reading American Accent Training by Ann Cook right now.

Comment: Hi Jim, I would stress "straw" in that scenario but the author of the book (Ann Cook) stressed "little" & "house", and for "little wooden house", she stressed "wooden". That's why I was a little confused..

Comment: @Nancy- why would you stress *straw* when the pertinent information is *the small one*.  You would stress *straw* if the situation was: "Quick hide in that little house."  "Which one? There's a brick one, a stick one and a straw one."  *Then* you would stress *straw* as you said, "The little *straw* house."

Comment: @Jim Oh. Sorry. I read it wrong. Yes, you're right.

Comment: These are the sentences: The first little pig built a little straw house. The second little pig built a small wooden house.

Comment: @Nancy- You should edit your question and add those sentences.  They are critical to knowing how the stress is placed.

Comment: The quoted sentences appear to be written in mostly-anapestic verse, with many three-syllable groups in which the first syllable is slightly stressed, the second syllable is unstressed, and the third syllable is strongly stressed.  The word "straw" is unstressed because of the metrical pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read the sentences in order, the important thing in sentence 1 is *what* is being built so *house* is stressed. The stresses on *little* and *straw* may be very similar, or may be slightly stronger on one or the other depending on the reader.

But when you start to read sentence 2, the context of 1 dictates where the stress in 2 should go. Both houses are *small* (*little* and *small* are essentially the same) and they are both houses thus *wooden*  becomes the distinguishing characteristic and is therefore the word to stress.

Comment: also: metrically, #1-second *little* #2-*small* and 1/2-*house* fall on strong downbeats; so strong that it takes a rise in pitch to shift the stress off of *small* onto *wooden* on the backbeat.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much Jim. Your answer totally makes sense.

Comment: This was my thought as well. As an exercise, try reading them in this order: _The first little pig built a little wooden house. The second little pig built a little straw house._ Sure, that would throw the big bad wolf for a loop, but it also might change what we stress in each of the sentences.